# @Formula and PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, postgresql, formula

I' using Hibernate 5 with PostgreSQL. All is fine but I've a problem with the @Formula annotation.

I've this entity

```
public class MyImage implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Lob
private byte[] content;
private Boolean favorite;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "father_id", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
private Father father;
```

and this

```
public class Father implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,mappedBy = "father")
private Set<MyImage> images;

@Formula("(select ai.content from my_image ai where ai.father_id = id and ai.favorite = 1)")
private byte[] neededBytes;
```

With MySQL is working fine, but with PostgreSQL I've some SQL Grammar Exception. Testing the @Formula's query inside the SQL editor, seems to be that for PostgreSQL istead of use

```
ai.favorite = 1
```

I need to use

```
ai.favorite = TRUE
```

but even if I change this query, I always get an SQL Grammar Exception.
Can you help me?

Comment: Can you show us an exact error message?

Comment: Here the stack. "Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet" and "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: The column advertisin0_.true doesn't exists. I'm not able to add all the stack